# How Do I Reconfigure My Cisco ASA in order to Move it to a Colocation Facility?

Tags: cisco-asa

My office DSL modem has a static IP address. In the ASA startup wizard, I connected to it using PPPoE.

I now have it configured VPN and NAT and tested it in this environment. This weekend, I am going to move my server and Cisco ASA to a colocation facility. The facility has provided me with the following information:

www.xxx.yyy.176/29 has been allocated for your port.

Allocation breakdown for www.xxx.yyy.176/29

Network: www.xxx.yyy.176 Broadcast: www.xxx.yyy.183 Netmask: 255.255.255.248 Gateway: www.xxx.yyy.177 Usable range: www.xxx.yyy.178 - www.xxx.yyy.182

The first usable IP address in the range is configured as the gateway.

Using the Startup Wizard, how would I reconfigure the Outside IP Address? (I assume that once this is done, my NAT and VPN configuration will continue to work).

Answer (score 0):

My Cisco ASA has now been succesfully moved to a colocation facility. An employee of the colocation provider assisted me by making the necessary changes.

1) Using the Startup Wizard, on the Interface IP Address Configuration page, the Outside IP address was changed from "Use PPPoE" to "Use the following IP address":

IP Address: www.xxx.yyy.178 (see "Usable range" in the question)

Mask: 255.255.255.248

2) On the DHCP Server page of the Startup Wizard, under the DHCP Parameters section, the DNS Servers were changed to (IP addresses provided by the colocation's engineer).

3) Using ASDM, the engineer then navigated to Device Setup, Routing, Static Routes and added the following Static Route:

IP Address Type: IPv4

Interface: outside

Network: any4

Gateway IP: www.xxx.yyy.177 (see "Gateway" in the question)

Metric: 1

Options: None

(When I was using PPPoE, at my office's location, there were no Static Routes defined).

In order to activate the changes, the network adapter was disabled and then enabled.

These changes being made, I now have VPN access, am able to connect to my servers using RDP, and my NAT configurations continue to work w/o modification.